# Исключение для .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Я плохо разбираюсь в htaccsess.
Так, у меня spa приложение. Фронт лежит в папке public, есть папка api, куда приходят запросы. И мне нужно перенаправлять все запросы на public/index.html, а запросы к api никуда не перенаправлять.

То есть мне нужно, чтобы `domain.com` = `domain.com/public/index.html`
И `domain.com/api/index.php?action=dialogs` = `domain.com/api/index.php?action=dialogs`

Вот мой `.htaccess`, он все в public перенаправляет.
Как сделать исключение?

```js
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Папка public не **должна торчать в корне сайта!** Это и есть корень сайта. Надо либо сделать два сервера, либо поместить папку api внутрь public

Comment: В laravel папка public в корне, не знаю, как там работает перенаправление, но public в корне

Comment: В laravel папка public НЕ в корне. Она и является корнем.

Comment: Да? Окей, тогда перенесу api в public

Comment: внутри нее можно будет положить .htaccess с командой rewriteengine off

Comment: Хотя это все странно. Почему ларавель не обрабатывает запросы к АПИ

Comment: Хм, так допустим url `domain.com/home`, то нужно перенаправить на `public/index.html`, а если `domain.com/api/index.php`, то нужно перенаправить на `public/api/index.php`

Comment: это ларавель или не ларавель? в ларавеле будет только один index.php, domain.com/index.php

Comment: Нет, это чистый php и react. Я просто на laravel использовал в прошлом проекте

Comment: ну тогда  в папку api положить свой .htaccess, он перезапишет действие корневого